# Wizz Air ticket cancellation

Tags: cancellations, refunds, wizz-air

I have to cancel my Wizz Air tickets due to visa problems. I have already checked in online for the outward journey on March 16th and return is March 23rd.

What if the Wizz Air cancellation fee is more than the air tickets?

Is it still sensible to cancel the tickets and expect the refund or just let go the money?

Comment: If the cancellation fee is greater than the air fare, they won't charge you extra not to take your flight.  Try to cancel.  You might (or might not) get something out of it, but you'll never know until you try.

Comment: As I have already checked in and today I got to know that I cant fly do u visa problems. 
What if they charge extra as I have given my credit card details.

Comment: Did they tell you at check in that you can't travel due to visa issues?  Or did you realize by yourself and now want to cancel?

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that you would get any refund - this a cheap airline, sorry. Worth trying though - you can give them a quick call.

Comment: I have used the Wizzair (hungarian company)  talked to their customer service, and you wont be able to cancel it. The best is postpone your journey.

Comment: @tom I can still travel but my wife cant.. This information I got it this morning.. As she has a Limited visa..

Comment: related: https://www.quora.com/I-want-to-cancel-my-flight-Wizzair-and-get-a-refund-How-do-I-do-that

Comment: What did you do in the end @1234?

Comment: My mother-in-law once cancelled a return flight from our place with Wizz Air and got back something like €19...which was then eaten up by the cost of the call to Wizz Air, as they use extra-toll lines.

Answer (score 5):

Wizz air website page says this

**Cancellations**

https://wizzair.com/en-GB/useful_information/faq

> It is not possible to cancel your booking online. As most
>   cancellation requests are of an urgent nature we kindly ask you to
>   contact our Call Centre immediately. Please note that cancellations
>   will be handled in accordance with our General Conditions of Carriage
>   (Article 6.5.1.).

**General Carriage of Conditions**

https://wizzair.com/en-GB/useful_information/general_conditions_of_carriage_list

> **6.5. Cancellation of Reservation by Passenger**
>
> Decree 22.§ (3), 25.§ and 26.§
>
> 6.5.1. You may cancel Your reservation up to the fourteenth (14th) day prior to the scheduled time of departure of Your flight. You will be
>   entitled to a refund of the Total Fare after deduction of the
>   Cancellation Fee.
>
> 6.5.2. If You cancel Your reservation within fourteen (14) days prior to the scheduled time of departure of Your flight, You will be
>   refunded the amount of the Total Fare after deduction of the Fee for
>   Other Services and the Seat Protection Fee.
>
> 6.5.3. In the case of death of an immediate family member (mother, father, grandparent, child, grandchild, sister, brother, wife,
>   husband, common law partner) within a month before the scheduled time
>   of departure of a flight in Your reservation, upon Your request
>   presented within 1 month of such death, We will cancel Your
>   reservation and refund You the Total Fare for that part of the
>   carriage that was not used provided that You present a death
>   certificate or copy thereof within 7 days after Your request.
>
> 6.5.4. In case Wizz Air changes the route or scheduled flight times included in Your Itinerary in accordance with Article 15.1, omits the
>   Agreed Stopping Place or adds a new stopping place, You may cancel the
>   Contract with immediate effect and You are entitled to a refund of the
>   Total Fare.

Answer (score 3):

Best option, call Wizzair, ask about cancelling or postponing the booking.

If the change fee or the cancellation fee costs less than the total airfare, then take advantage of whichever is a better deal.

If the cancellation and change fees are greater than the airfare, leave the booking in place and simply don't fly.  If you are a No Show they will automatically cancel your booking and keep your money. There is no cancellation fee for this because it is considered an 'involuntary' cancellation.  Cancellation fees apply only to 'voluntary' cancellations ('voluntary' cancellations to the airlines means ANY cancellation you initiate and they don't care why you initiated it).

Answer (score 1):

Did you bought any kind of insurance or a full economy ( flexible ) fare ? If not :

You will just lose the money spent to buy the flight ticket. Basically you have jun an other option , try to ask a refund on the part of the airport taxes that do not include any surcharge as fuel ( but Wizzair will answer you that is not possible to have any kind of a refund )

Then I really suggest you to do not waste your time and money in unnecessary action .